# To fixed subheader right under Main Header

Tags: html, angular-material

I am using Angular-Material to get this right. You can check the [codepen here](http://codepen.io/infacq/pen/ZGabYq). As you can see, I failed to get the subheader to fixed right under the main header. What have I missed?

here is the HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <header md-page-header>
    <div md-header-picture style="background-image:url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-8jk6pwVieck/TiDjWyDdWHI/AAAAAAAAAbQ/n22FFKf9bvs/s1600/259699_219094411455453_214219875276240_696700_4217591_o.jpg)"></div>
    <md-toolbar scroll>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <md-button class="md-tools" aria-label="Go Back">
          <md-icon aria-label="keyboard_arrow_left" class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <h2 md-header-title flex>Sari Yanti</h2>
        <md-button class="md-tools" aria-label="Edit Contact"><md-icon aria-label="assistant Photo" class="material-icons">&#xE3A0;</md-icon></md-button>
        <md-button class="md-tools" aria-label="More"><md-icon aria-label="assistant Photo" class="material-icons">&#xE3E3;</md-icon></md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div class="main-fab">
      <md-button aria-label="Float Action Button" class="md-fab md-accent"><md-icon aria-label="airline_seat_recline_extra" class="material-icons">&#xE636;</md-icon></md-button>
    </div>
  </header>
  <md-content ng-controller="SubheaderAppCtrl" md-theme="altTheme">
    <section>
      <md-subheader class="md-primary">Unread Messages</md-subheader>
      <md-list layout-padding>
        <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="message in messages">
            <img ng-src="{{message.face}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{message.who}}">
            <div class="md-list-item-text">
              <h3>{{message.what}}</h3>
              <h4>{{message.who}}</h4>
              <p>
                {{message.notes}}
              </p>
            </div>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
    </section>
    <section>
      <md-subheader class="md-warn">Late Messages</md-subheader>
      <md-list layout="column" layout-padding>
        <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="message in messages">
          <img ng-src="{{message.face}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{message.who}}">
          <div class="md-list-item-text">
            <h3>{{message.what}}</h3>
            <h4>{{message.who}}</h4>
            <p>
              {{message.notes}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
    </section>
    <section>
      <md-subheader>Read Messages</md-subheader>
      <md-list layout="column" layout-padding>
        <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="message in messages">
          <img ng-src="{{message.face}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{message.who}}">
          <div class="md-list-item-text">
            <h3>{{message.what}}</h3>
            <h4>{{message.who}}</h4>
            <p>
              {{message.notes}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
    </section>
    <section>
      <md-subheader class="md-accent">Archived messages</md-subheader>
      <md-list layout="column" layout-padding>
        <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="message in messages">
          <img ng-src="{{message.face}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{message.who}}">
          <div class="md-list-item-text">
            <h3>{{message.what}}</h3>
            <h4>{{message.who}}</h4>
            <p>
              {{message.notes}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </md-list-item>
      </md-list>
    </section>
  </md-content>
  </div>
```

Looks like this angular-material only target the mobile. But I do really hope it can used on the web as well

Answer (score 0):

First you have an extra  in your html

```
<span class="ng-scope">Unread Messages</span></span>
```

Second, I think when screen scrolls up the image header disappears and the tool bar appears, if you want the "Unread Messages" after that tool bar, put

```
<h2 class="md-primary md-subheader md-altTheme-theme" sticky-state="next">
  <div class="md-subheader-inner"><span class="md-subheader-content">
    <span class="ng-scope">Unread Messages</span>
  </div>
</h2>
```

inside the **md-toolbar-tools** and conditionally show it the same way how you are showing the toolbar

I have forked and modified your code to show or hide the sub header using the same logic you where doing, CodePen here: http://codepen.io/zigmaempire/pen/doZzwe

Comment: try check my pen again. It doesn't work. why don't you fork and show yours

Comment: Edited and added the forked code, I am using html attribute like fixed-subheader and floating-subheader, you can modify as you want, hope it works :)

Comment: what is `sticky-state="next"`?

Comment: Refer this https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky for Sticky States